# How to add text and icon to Android button center it?

Tags: android

I have a circular button that is in a table so its 2x2. The issue is the buttons are huge and the image and text are really far apart. See image below.

How can I shrink the buttons so they are about half the width/height. And move the icon more downward to center of the button. Maybe decreasing the buttons height/width will move the icon more into position.

[image]

CODE:

Activity:

```
                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/call_requester"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:background="@drawable/circlebuttonshape"
                        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_call_black_24dp"
                        android:text="Call" />


                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/text_requester"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/circlebuttonshape"
                        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_chat_bubble_black_24dp"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:text="Text" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/add_dump_fee"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/circlebuttonshape"
                        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_credit_card_black_24dp"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:text="Fee"
                        android:onClick="confirmFee"/>

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/confirm_change_type"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/circlebuttonshape"
                        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_people_black_24dp"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:text="XL"
                        android:onClick="confirmChangeType"/>
                </TableRow>

            </TableLayout>
```

CircleButton:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<stroke android:width="4px" android:color="#ffffff" />
<padding
    android:bottom="4dp"
    android:left="4dp"
    android:right="4dp"
    android:top="4dp" />
```

Vector:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
<path
    android:fillColor="#fffafafa"
    android:pathData="M20,4L4,4c-1.11,0 -1.99,0.89 -1.99,2L2,18c0,1.11 0.89,2 2,2h16c1.11,0 2,-0.89 2,-2L22,6c0,-1.11 -0.89,-2 -2,-2zM20,18L4,18v-6h16v6zM20,8L4,8L4,6h16v2z"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:orientation="vertical">

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/call_requester"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/circlebuttonshape"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_tick_expand"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Call"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/text_requester"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/circlebuttonshape"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_tick_expand"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Text"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add_dump_fee"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/circlebuttonshape"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_tick_expand"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Fee"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/confirm_change_type"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/circlebuttonshape"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_tick_expand"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="XL"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</TableRow>
```

Comment: TESTED...Please try this layout file, it will help you, i am sure.

Comment: It sort of works. It brings the image and text closer together so that is fine now. However, the circles are still the same size (giant). Also, the button inside the LinearLayout is not a circle. You can see the button as a rectangle. So it now looks like a rectangle inside a circle, with the button and text in the center.

Comment: Thanks. How do I make the circles half the size? More like height and width of the circle as 50dpx50dp instead of the 100dpx100dp?

Comment: Once again I have edited My Answer. check it that. It will remove your giant circle

Comment: Also, now that the background is transparent, the user cannot see feedback that the button was clicked?

Comment: it will never see feedback, when you apply custom backgground to button

Answer (score 0):

Use this structure instead of plain Button

```
 <FrameLayout
  android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
android:background="@drawable/circlebuttonshape" >
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical">
<ImageView/>
<TextView/>

</LinearLayout>
</Framelayout>
```

Comment: How does it act like a button then?

Answer (score 0):

A better fix is to make use of the wealth of Unicode symbols - embed a Unicode symbol icon to the left of your text on the button, without having to resort to these layout hacks. You can keep the whole thing centered easily as per a text button.